# Vue js v-text-field formating date

Tags: vue.js

I retrieve date from my backend like this: dd-mm-YYYY. But when I have v-text-field with type date it display the date in such format YYYY-mm-dd. Is there a way to change it to display the date in this format (dd-mm-YYYY)?

```
<v-text-field    
                  :type="date"
                  :attr-name="attribute.name"
                  v-model="attribute.value"

              />
```